# Consuming a WCF with an Identity set on Endpoint: correct UPN does not work

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services

I wrote a Windows Service hosted WCF service. Deployed or localhost works fine, my client app can consume it.

If I change the LogOn setting of the Windows Service and set a domain user (changing from the default "Local System") my client app cannot consume the service anymore. The exception I get is

```
A call to SSPI failed
```

There is no inner exception or any details. To fix this I tried to set the UPN in my client app request in order to get a valid service name check. This is done, client side, via code, setting an Identity in the endpoint:

```
string uri = "myServiceUri";
EndpointIdentity identity = EndpointIdentity.CreateSpnIdentity("user@domain");
EndpointAddress epa = new EndpointAddress(uri, identity, new AddressHeader[] { });
```

There comes the very strange behavior.

- If I set the exact UPN in my client request, lets say "user@domain",
  I get a new exception (no inner exception, no details)

  ```
  The following remote identity failed verification: 'user@domain'
  ```
- If I set any other string as UPN in my client request, it works fine,
  let's say "*XXXuser@domainXXX*", "*toto*", or even *String.Empty*.

Server side, I did not set any Identity node in config file to keep default behavior, ie UPN check (no SPN nor DNS).

In other words, the Service/User name check seems to work only if the settings in my client app is *wrong*.

Dear community, your help would be very appreciated on this topic.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is... use `CreateUpnIdentity` instead of `CreateSpnIdentity` to let WCF handle the UPN properly.

The reason is that without any Identity node in the server config file *and* with a domain account as service user, the default identity exposed by service is the UPN "account@domain".

Answer (score 0):

I seem to recall that using a non-existent UPN will force authentication to fall back from Kerberos to NTLM. To get Kerberos working with a domain account I think you'll need to configure an SPN for the target account: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628618.aspx

Comment: It seems to be a fairly good point. But I found a better one, with your answer: simply use `CreateUpnIdentity` instead of `CreateSpnIdentity`. WCF handles name checking. Thanks @IanGilroy for the solution-catalysor.